# Can I declare a HashMap<key> instead of a HashMap<key,value>?

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to insert keys into a hashmap but I don't really need values inserted. I could but they wouldn't be used. I know hashmaps can accept null keys and values but only one null key,value pair. I could `map.put(key,null)` with the values being null but that method seems inefficient. My intention is that I'm going to use the `map.containsKey(key)` method to determine if a key exists in a hashmap which is why I don't need a value.

With that being said, is there a way to declare `HashMap<key>` instead of `HashMap<key,arbitraryValue>` so I won't have to add unnecessary null values? Sorry if this may be a dumb question.

Comment: The data type that you're looking for is called a `Set<E>`.

Comment: Why do you need a `HashMap` if you don't need key value pairs? Why not just use a list or a set?

Comment: The `HashSet` class that you should be using, is implemented using `HashMap`, so apprently it’s not so inefficient as one might think. Don’t worry about it.

Comment: I think Google might have an implementation of the HashSet that you might find interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Jacob G.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7294647/jacob-g) said, you should use a [`Set<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).

A set is just a collection that does not contain any duplicates. The implementing class [`HashSet<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) actually uses a `HashMap<K,V>` under the hood, as mentioned by [Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772882/ole-v-v), but using a `Set<E>` in your code is the better approach IMO, because your problem does not require the values.

Additionally, there is a problem with using a `HashMap<K,V>` where all your values are `null` is in the `get(K key)` method. This method will return `null` if the requested `key` does not have an associated value. So how do you know if your call to `get` returned a valid or invalid `null`? i.e.

```
Map<Integer, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

// add entry 0 -> 
map.put(0, null);

Object get1 = map.get(0); // returns null, so 0 must be a key in our map!
Object get2 = map.get(1); // also returns null, so is 1 a key too? No!
```

So, for your specific problem, I would try something like this!

```
Set<MyKey> set = new HashSet<>(); // or any implementing class

...

MyKey someKey = ...

// Check if your key set doesn't have some key, if so add it to the key set
if (!set.contains(someKey)) {
  set.add(someKey);
}
```